# Why I am unable to use Why3 API in my OCaml code?

Tags: ocaml, why3

I downloaded the Why3 tarball and installed using make and `make install-lib` as given in the documentation for Why3 API. But still when I do `open Why3`, ocamlc and utop complain `unbound module Why3`.

Can someone please help me how to use Whye API from OCaml code?

I am following instructions give here http://why3.lri.fr/doc/install.html.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
make byte opt
make install-lib
```

Comment: which compilation command are you typing exactly?

Comment: @ghilesZ added to the question.

Comment: actually i was referring to then file where you're typing "open Why3". How do you compile it?

Comment: Either using `ocamlc` or I write `open Why3` in utop.

Comment: @ghilesZ `ocamlc k.ml` where k.ml has `open Why3`

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler where to look for why3 and its dependencies. Assuming you installed everything in DIR:

```
ocamlc -I DIR/num -I DIR/zip -I DIR/menhirLib -I DIR/why3 \
 unix.cma str.cma dynlink.cma nums.cma zip.cma menhirLib.cmo why3.cma \
 yourfile.ml
```

Or more easily if you have ocamlfind (I advise you to, or better, use a build system that supports ocamlfind).

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package why3 \
 unix.cma str.cma dynlink.cma nums.cma zip.cma menhirLib.cmo why3.cma \
 yourfile.ml
```

Comment: now I am getting error `Reference to undefined global `Why3'`. I think this is because it can not find Why3 compiled module to link. How can I resolve it?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar edited. This should do the trick. Note that using a build tool (like jbuilder or oasis) would solve your problem.